# Do Machine Learning and Vision Labs outside the USA hire non-student,non-postdoc Research Assistants?

Tags: research-process, computer-science, research-assistantship

I am currently on a visiting research assistant position at a US university for a year. My visa will not allow me to start a similar position in the US after this stint is over, and I am looking for another yearlong research position before I start a Masters/PhD program from Fall 2015.

My current research involves Vision with Graphical Models. I am interested in pursuing research in Vision, or Computational Biology involving Graphical Models and Machine Learning methods.

So is it possible to work as a Research Assistant in this field, outside the USA, without a doctorate, and without being a student?

Comment: This question asks for a list of resources, and is therefore not suitable for the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: With the new edits this seems like a perfectly good question. It should re-opened

Comment: Don't you find industry more lucrative than academia?

Comment: @user10694 _lucrative_ in the sense of money or contribution to the human kind?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to the question "is it possible?": yes, it is. E.g. in Germany, we can employ a person having some academic degree. The more important question is: What would you be willing to earn because at least in Germany, academic position usually are not the best paid ones.

If you just want to earn money and get experience, I would recommend a job in industry. If you really want to learn and develop yourself, and you don't have to earn much, look around in Europe. If you bring your own money (e.g. DAAD scholarship), you could start in my lab ;o).

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! I heard from a friend that in the UK you can work in paid research positions only if you're at least pursuing a PhD. I am interested in "learning and development" rather than making money right now, because I'm planning to start a PhD program late next year, and it would make sense to stay in touch with research in the meantime. "Enough money" would be fine for me. So if I apply to a lab/professor, will that person help with the DAAD stuff, or do I have to apply on my own? (BTW, I'm an Indian citizen, not a US one)

Comment: I had a PhD candidate from Egypt in my lab and I helped preparing the DAAD stuff, but still he had to do most of the work. You can check out their website regarding India at http://www.daaddelhi.org/en/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I took a look at the available funding schemes for Indian nationals, and it looks like there is no suitable scheme for someone in my position. The only funding I could get would be if I went for a short term internship (2-3 months), or for a Masters programme. So looks like DAAD is no good here. Thanks again for your time.